# Android Emulator not showing the default Android Wifi in Mac M1

Tags: macos, android-emulator, apple-m1

I am using a Macbook Pro with the M1 chip. I installed

> Android Studio 4.2.1 Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7351085, built on May
> 10, 2021 Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264 x86_64 VM: OpenJDK
> 64-Bit Server VM by N/A macOS 10.16 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old
> Generation Memory: 1280M Cores: 8 Registry:
> external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

I created the following device based on the instructions from [this.](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/my-journey-to-setup-android-emulator-for-m1-macbook-pro-b8365321b3e7)

> Name: Pixel_4_API_S
> CPU/ABI: Google APIs ARM (arm64-v8a)
> Path: /Users/vineethpalani/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_S.avd
> Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level S)
> Skin: pixel_4
> SD Card: 512M
> fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile:
> runtime.network.speed: full
> hw.accelerometer: yes
> hw.device.name: pixel_4
> hw.lcd.width: 1080
> image.androidVersion.codename: S
> hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
> image.androidVersion.api: 30
> tag.id: google_apis
> hw.mainKeys: no
> hw.camera.front: emulated
> avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 4 API S
> hw.gpu.mode: auto
> hw.ramSize: 1536
> PlayStore.enabled: false
> fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
> hw.cpu.ncore: 4
> hw.keyboard: yes
> hw.sensors.proximity: yes
> hw.dPad: no
> hw.lcd.height: 2280
> vm.heapSize: 256
> skin.dynamic: yes
> hw.device.manufacturer: Google
> hw.gps: yes
> hw.audioInput: yes
> image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-S/google_apis/arm64-v8a/
> showDeviceFrame: yes
> hw.camera.back: virtualscene
> AvdId: Pixel_4_API_S
> hw.lcd.density: 440
> hw.arc: false
> hw.device.hash2: MD5:6b5943207fe196d842659d2e43022e20
> fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
> fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
> hw.trackBall: no
> hw.battery: yes
> hw.sdCard: yes
> tag.display: Google APIs
> runtime.network.latency: none
> disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
> hw.sensors.orientation: yes
> avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
> hw.gpu.enabled: yes

Although I am able to run the device, it doesn't have access to internet, nor was its Wifi enabled.
[image]
[image]

Even if I switch Wifi on, it would switch back off. I also tried adding the DNS based on what internet searches revealed. I trying restarting, switching on and off both the Wifi as as well the device.
[image]

Nothing seems to work. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I am facing similar issue, have you found any solution on this ?

Comment: Same here, I've played with the network settings but it seems like the interface is not initialising

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Install one of the newest canary versions of Android Studio. Use the MAC ARM version (Apple Silicon).
2. When creating a new virtual device use API Level S and arm64 virtual image. (could be found in other images)

Here is the link for the android studio releases list:
https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Comment: What will happen to my previous Rosetta android studio installation if I install the ARM one?